# How to copy movie files from old, damaged CDs?

Tags: finder, optical-drive

I have a number of old, old CD-ROMs with large AVI and other movie files on them (usually one file per CD).

When I try to copy the files over in finder, it eventually fails with error -36. I assume this is because some sectors on the CD have become faulty.

Is there an error-tolerant way to copy over the files, including the faulty sectors, to see whether the files work anyway (with maybe a few minutes missing)?

Comment: New CD/DVD drive is the least headache - 20 bucks, these days - chances are it's the drive not the disk. btw, movies with bad data will not skip the bad segments, they will just halt, with no way past.

Comment: @Tetsujin didn't think about that, will try with a different drive!

Comment: @Pekka 웃, Before going out a buying a new optical drive, test copy a disc that had issues on your drive, on another drive on a different computer of a friend maybe.  If it has the same issues as on yours then it's the disc not the drive. To get past the bad sectors you can use `ddrescue` or `dd` either of which should be able to skip the bad sectors as there no sense in copying the bad sectors.  See want you can get off the disc that way.